# Use the same search method in the whole app in Swift

Tags: swift, inheritance, search, protocols

I'm new in Swift and develop an app with a glossary in one controller with a searchbar and methods associated through UISearchBarDelegate. And I'd like to use exactly the same methods in other controllers.

I already put the glossary data in a singleton, but how to use the search methods without copying all the methods. Can I simply make the other controller inherit from my GlossaryController? But what about the protocol?

Comment: Tableview is only displaying your data. While you search something, you need to create some array (data source) for tableview. So it's a bad idea to use number of tableview you using instead of 1. in other way should split your array to the parts and send each part to own tableview.

Comment: I don't want to show the result in the same tableview but in the kind of "autocomplete textview" like in android. The result is show only when a research begin. It works fine.I just want a way to avoid copying all required methods from searchbar delegate.

Comment: Let me know how many tableView you using in your project

Comment: For this specific design, I use 2 tableviews, one to display data, and onother one, in an overlay view, to display the search result. But this search result can also be show above an image, to find informations in it

Comment: You don't need to use 2 tableview to search and display result. You can do this from the same tableview...let me know I can help you with the code for you... this means you can do all your stuff from the same tableview...

Comment: I know that and know how to proceed when the tableview displays only texts. But I have also tableview with images and info in these images I want to search, like abbreviation for ex. And I want to display the result in an overlay tableview (what I know to do). What I don't know is how to reproduce the search method in different controllers without copying everything

Comment: Populating tableViewCell with image is exactly same as  populating String...

Comment: If you really want to do this.You need to save your data array into a common place.that where you can access that data for your search result etc....You can do this in two ways as i know you can access your data from anywhere if you set data inside your  AppDelegate or Save data array into plist and you can access it from anywhere .But, You need to workout lot of things to achieve this function and there is no easy way around.i recommend you to google it first and then proceed....

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new swift file and put your methods there. Then, they will be accessible from any other file you have...

Comment: That I wanted to do, but I wonder if it could work even with methods from search delegate

Comment: @FlorentBreton You mean to somehow make the search delegate methods you'll override, global?

Answer (score 0):

@Sotiris:
Exactly. I override several methods from search delegate, like

```
   // MARK: - Search Bar delegate
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {    }

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {    }

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {    }

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {    }

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {}
```

As my controllers implement UISearchBarDelegate, they need to override this methods (or some of them). 
If I create a class that implement the delegate and override these methods, can I call this new class in controllers without they don't need to implement UISearchBarDelegate anymore.